# Bringing the cold water to room temperature

Tags: temperature, water

In my office the water dispenser either gives very hot water or very cold water. So I am forced to mix both to bring the water to normal temperature, or I have to wait for some time to bring it to room temperature. As I do not like the taste of hot water, I prefer to take the cold water in a bottle and wait for 1 or 2 hour to come up to room temperature. Are there any other alternative idea for this. I hope many face this issue. Please advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bring to work sufficient bottles to cover an entire day's supply.

Fill them in the evening with cold water.

The next day they will be the correct temperature, all day.

Repeat by refilling in the evening.

There is no risk in leaving them filled for 2 extra days over the weekend.

If this would result in too many bottles, the alternative would be shorten the number required to 'the length of time taken to achieve correct temperature plus time taken to drink divided into day length.'
If a bottle takes 2 hours to reach temperature & 2 hours to drink, then 2 bottles would be sufficient.

You could still start with them all full each evening.

Comment: Good idea. I feel this one safer than mixing hot and cold water. Thank you very much...

Comment: It's a little risky.  I've had water grow life forms within the span of two days, not so easy on the stomach.

Comment: You do have to make sure the bottles are clean, of course.. & we're not talking about pond water here - any domestic water supply that could start growing things inside 2 days would need some very serious investigation... or preferably a move to another country :/

Comment: I often use home filled (but clean to start with) bottles of water a few weeks after filling, with no visible growths nor bad results. (Good quality tap water helps.)

Answer (score 5):

**Microwave the cold water to temp.**

The temperature of a water coolers is pretty consistent. If you have your favorite glass or plastic tumbler (a known quantity of water), then you'll get to know *exactly* how long it takes to heat up the cold water to the *perfect* temperature.

The advantage of this over "store water elsewhere" is that heating it on demand takes no advanced planning; you don't have to set aside water in sufficient quantities for later consumption. And if you like your water **just a bit warmer or cooler than room temperature**, you can control that too!

Answer (score 4):

Mix the two together sequentially.  That is, fill it up partially with cold water and finish the rest with hot.  After a while you will learn the best point in the cup to stop with one and switch to the other.

Alternatively, get water from a regular tap instead of a water heater/cooler, or bring your own in a reusable bottle.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the a water bottle that's cold in a bucket or container and put it under running hot water or vice versa. Only keep the bottle there for about 2-3 minutes, but if you keep it there for too long, do the other way. Example: You have a cold water bottle so you put it in a bucket and put it under running hot water, but you leave it there too long so it's really hot now. All you have to do is put it under cold water, but for a little bit this time. After all of that, it should be good.

Comment: Why are there so many thumbs down?

Comment: Maybe because of the [first revision](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/revisions/19490/1) of your post ...

Comment: Oh sorry someone was on here before and they showed me this so I could answer it. They probably typed something, submitted it, clicked edit, deleted all of it, and then showed me a blank area for me to start typing. I will go talk to the person who was on.